# SBT multi-project build without using lazy vals

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working with a huge project with lots of subprojects, some of them with subprojects of their own. On top of that, I'd like some of them to be dynamic - given a `List` somewhere in the project build, I'd like to create one project for each of the elements.

For those reasons, having to define a `lazy val` for each project in `build.sbt` is very cumbersome. Is there other way to declare projects, like a `addProject`-like method we could call anywhere? Is there some SBT plugin that helps with that?

Answer (score 1):

Sbt uses macros to turns top level `val`s into projects, so I don't think you will be able to escape that part. However, you can define all you build in `Project => Project` functions: (note that you also composability "for free" with function composition)

```
def myConf: Project => Project =
  _.enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
   .settings(scalaVersion := "2.12.0")
```

Then simply use `project.configure(myConf)` for single line project definitions:

```
lazy val subProject1 = project.configure(myConf)
lazy val subProject2 = project.configure(myConf)
lazy val subProject3 = project.configure(myConf)
lazy val subProject4 = project.configure(myConf)
...
```